# MacOS throwing dyld Error when running kafkacat

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, kcat

I want to use kafkacat command line utility(https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html) on my MacOS Mojave(10.14.5). I executed the below steps

```
brew install kafkacat

kafkacat -C -b brokerID -t kafkaTopic -e -K '+'
```

I am getting the error as below

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _timespec_get
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/librdkafka/lib/librdkafka.1.dylib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _timespec_get   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/opt/librdkafka/lib/librdkafka.1.dylib   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> Abort trap: 6

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling kafkacat.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Looks like it is coming from librdkafka: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/pull/2569 and the last version of Xcode (11). You can either:

- Uninstall librdkafka / kafkacat brew version (`brew uninstall ...`). Rebuild librdkafka using the "fixed" branch and then rebuild kafkacat (method I tested) OR
- Downgrade Xcode to 10.x

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing same error with `librdkafka` in macOS Mojave ver. 10.14.6, I had installed **Xcode 11.x**.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _timespec_get
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/librdkafka/lib/librdkafka.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _timespec_get
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/librdkafka/lib/librdkafka.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lidyld: lazy symbol binding failedb/libSystem.B: Symbol not found: _timespec_ge.dylib
```

I found an open issue in [Blizzard/node-rdkafka](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/686) describing the same error. As suggested, I downgraded Xcode from `11.x` to `10.3`, then rebuild `librdkafka`

```
brew install --build-from-source librdkafka
```

**It worked!**

By the way, it looks like [the fix](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/pull/2569) for `librdkafka` has just been merged into master.

Answer (score 2):

The below worked for me after I read about the issue in https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/pull/2569

I uninstalled kafkacat and then librdkafka

brew uninstall kafkacat
brew uninstall librdkafka

Then I installed the latest version of kibrdkafka that has the fix but is not available in brew yet like below

brew install librdkafka --HEAD

Then installed kafkacat again

brew install kafkacat

Now the errors are gone and the consumer is connected.
Note my XCode version is 11.2.1

Answer (score 1):

```
brew uninstall librdkafka
brew uninstall kafkacat
```

Apart from downgrading Xcode from 11.x to 10.3, installing Command Line Tools for Xcode 10.3 was also required. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Downgrading xcode => https://medium.com/@tseboho/how-to-downgrade-xcode-4359df5158d5

```
brew install --build-from-source librdkafka
brew install kafkacat
```